# KeyBoard extension Interrupted on iOS swift app. works fine on simulator but does not work on device

Tags: ios, swift, simulator, interrupted-exception, ios-keyboard-extension

I have built an iOS app with Swift that uses keyboard extension. Works awesome on simulator in all devices but when i  run it in my phone the app alone works but the keyboard does not work. NSLOG shows bundle name interrupted.

Why is this and how to get past this?

Comment: Are you possibly taking too long?  iOS is incredibly strict with how much CPU time extensions can use.

Comment: @sapi had the same problem and finaly found the problem with your hint